# Utilities.formatDate displaying wrong date - incorrect date format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, datetime-format

My code updates the Date column (formatted as Date) whenever the user enters in data in the comments column.

This script worked for a while, but then stoped working.

```
function UpdateDate() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { 
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if(r.getRow() > 2 && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue()) { 
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
     
       var time = new Date();
     time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST-05:00", "MM-DD-YY");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

Whenever I update the comment section now I'm getting 2/35/15, which is obviously incorrect. I can't figure out what's causing the issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the date part of your code to this:  And it seems to be working.

```
function UpdateDate() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var stringAsDate = "";
  stringAsDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST-05:00", "MM-dd-yy");
  Logger.log(stringAsDate);
}
```

The full code would be:

```
function UpdateDate() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { 
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if(r.getRow() > 2 && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue()) { 
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);

     var stringAsDate = "";
     stringAsDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST-05:00", "MM-dd-yy");
     nextCell.setValue(stringAsDate);
   };
 };
}
```

You don't need the `time` variable.  `Utilities.formatDate()` returns a string, so there is no sense setting the variable `time` to a date type.

Comment: I just tried the code and it works! Thanks. Is there a difference between DD and dd? and why was it working just fine before and all of a sudden stop working?

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe they changed the underlying code to `Utilities.formatDate()`?  I just used the lower case because that is what the documentation showed.  Don't know if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

`D` is day in year whereas `d` is day in month. `DD` and `dd` are the zero padded versions. You were potentially asking for the 300th day in January.

```
time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST-05:00", "MM-dd-YY");
```

The [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) apps script uses is as per Java.